# Different output between IDE launch version and jar version of the same program

Tags: java, batch-file, javafx, encoding, character-encoding

I have a javafx program that runs fine in the IDE but that have problems with encoding/charset when started from a batch file.

So, let's say I have this code:

```
String lol = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM", new Locale("fr")).format(startDate);
String lol2 = "août";
int lol3 = lol.compareTo(lol2);
System.out.println(String.format("Voici la différence entre %s et %s: %d", lol, lol2, lol3));
```

When I run this in the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate), I get this output:

```
Voici la différence entre août et août: 0
```

When I run this with a batch file, I get this output:

```
Voici la diffÃ©rence entre août et aoÃ»t: 56
```

My batch file is as follow:

```
start java -DdefaultCharset=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar cs-build-master-1.0.0.jar
```

I am completely puzzled by this! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am using shadowJar to export my jar file. Here is the gradle code:

```
jfx {
    // minimal requirement for jfxJar-task
    mainClass = 'com.lol.csbuildmaster.MainApp'

    // minimal requirement for jfxNative-task
    vendor = 'Lol'
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'cs-build-master'
    classifier = null
    version = "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: If I had to take a guess, then the compiler is using the wrong charset. And you probably use the wrong charset for the console too.

Comment: My guess: You make java use UTF8 as charset which does not match the character encoding of the command line...